# Changing x-axis range in MATLAB without including ticks

Tags: matlab, plot

Two of my data points are barely visible:

[image]

based on this code:

```
x = 1:8;
y = [70 74 77 78 80 80 82 83];
err = [14 11 12 10 10 7 7 5];
errorbar(x,y,err,'red')
ylabel('Classification results','fontsize',20);
xlabel('Nr of features used', 'fontsize',20);
title('Feature selection with Genetic Algorithm','fontsize',24)
ylim([55 100])
```

Comment: Simply change range using, for example,  `caxis` function

Comment: well no because then it shows me "0" which is not a possible number of features...or do you mean something else?

Comment: What exactly are you after? I don't understand your problem statement.  Two of your points are barely visible.... OK, that's a statement - so what is your question?

Comment: How can I change the axis range that it gets wider, without including ticks such as "0", ie while still only having ticks from 1 to 8?

Comment: @MikhailGenkin I don't understand how `caxis` applies here.  There is no colour map to display - it's only a plot.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant use `axis` function: `axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])`,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`xlim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) and permute the beginning and end ranges by a slight amount... say 0.2:

```
xlim([min(x) - 0.2, max(x) + 0.2]);
```

I use `min` and `max` here to make it adaptive so that the smallest `x` value displayed is the smallest one in `x` subtracted by a 0.2 buffer.  Similar logic is applied for the largest `x` value where the value displayed is the largest one with a 0.2 buffer added.

I now get:

[image]